# Where can I get help transcribing and translating Danish records?

Tags: denmark, transcriptions

I do a lot of research in Danish parish registers, and often find these hard to read. I'd like to find a website where I can submit an image of a record and get help transcribing and translating it. What are my options? Is this site the right place?

For example, I'm trying to understand what [this record](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Image%3aKatinka_kristiansen_birth_record_-_data_kirkeboeger_O431_A_008_K02-09-A.png) says about the girl born on April 26th. My best-effort transcription and translation are given alongside the image of the record.

Comment: https://www.slaegtogdata.dk/forum/index.php/board,3.0.html has good help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the Denmark forum on familysearch.org. The familysearch.org forums include very active volunteers who are very generous in contributing their time and expertise, including help with translation. I scanned the Denmark forum and saw that there were recent posts asking for translation, and replies giving help and translations. You'll want to drill down as follows: FamilySearch Forums > Research and Record Assistance > Localities> Europe > Nordic Countries > Denmark.

Comment: It took me more steps to get there: Help > Community Assistance > Go to Forums

Comment: The Family Search forums closed.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

your link gives some answer - you probably got som help elsewhere :-)

From the link:

Danish: Moderen finde 10/12 Aar for Nedkomsten hi Gaardhus Kane i Skalkendrup trinsedt 30 Mai fra Nyborg; kviddaret 4 Juni 1884 [???]

English: The mother find 10/12 years of confinement hi farmhouse Kane in Skalkendrup trinsedt 30 Mai from Nyborg; kviddaret June 4, 1884

maybe should be ->

Danish: Moderen tjente 10/12 Aar for Nedkomsten hos Gaardens Kone i Skalkendrup Anmeldt[?] 30 Mai fra Nyborg; Kvitteret 4 Juni 1884

English: The mother worked 10/12 years for the birth for the farms housewife in Skalkendrup. Declared 30 Mai from Nyborg; Acknowledged June 4, 1884

that is - if I can read/translate it correctly. The farmwife wanted compensation for taking care of Johanne and her child. Somehow the law/community was involved too - hence the formalties from the large city of Nyborg. Not sure...

Comment: The transcription and translation on the link were my best efforts. Thanks for your contribution here. So was this the arrangement for unwed mothers---have them work for a farm family in the country for 10 months covering the period of their pregnancy?

Comment: It seems that the fine was a year’s wager for the father and ½ a year for the mother. It was pretty common that it only was the woman who was punished since there  were no DNA tests at the time and the alleged father could deny… Some fled – but again, the mother usually stayed behind in order to take care of her child.

As far as I can see the steward of the estate was the one giving the fine – payment was received and handed over to the squire. If the guilty couldn’t pay they were ordered to work or/and work. A good way to have some cheap labor...

I hope somebody else can help better than I